# Object/Camera Stutter When Looping

Tags: camera, loop

I am working on this video where the camera is flying along the ground for around 90 seconds as the sun rises, to save making a massive scene i created a looping terrain and have the camera keyframed to snap back to the start when it loops, to give the illusion that it is just continuously flying. I am using a copy location constraint on the sun and sky in the background, copying the camera movement so it remains in the background (I first used parenting but didn't want the sun and sky to copy the camera rotation, just x location values). For the most part i have the look i want, but when in rendered view the sky and sun look like they get smaller in the last frame of the loop, stutter if you will. Furthermore, when i rendered out the video it was still visible and there was also an orange colour glitch happening every time it looped (I'm guessing these two problems are linked).

Here is a screenshot of the colour glitch happening when rendered out
[image]

To see what i mean its best you look at the project file which i have attached. Am not sure how to fix this glitch or stutter? I thought it was a problem with my keying so i redid them all in different methods but still get the same problem. I then thought the copy location was lagging by a frame but that seemed unlikely as i had the same problem when using parenting. Have been running in circles the last week or so with this so any info or help would be much appreciated, thanks!

[image]

Comment: It's best if you don't link readers of your question to external site/resources. We're asking for the help of strangers, after all, and people's attention resources are limited. Consider posting screenshots or short gifs within the body of your question itself. In addition, it can be VERY helpful to share your blend file, which can be done using https://blend-exchange.com.

Comment: Thank you, im new and didn't know how to share my file.

Comment: Do you have motion blur turned on by any chance? Also, I once encountered another question where someone wanted to make endless terrain, and I suggested they use a moving noise texture in a displacement modifier. Would this work for you?

Comment: @TheLabCat I do have motion blur turned on. And i see, rather than having the camera looping back and forth i would animate the noise texture that i have in the displacement modifier, so it loops 360 degrees in the x value? And keep the camera still so it looks as though the ground is moving under me? Smart! haha